# Can sunlight produce electric current in this case?

Tags: electromagnetism

As we know change in magnetic flux can create electric field(by Faraday's law). If we have a metal plate at earth under sunlight shouldn't there be some magnetic flux passing through that conducting plate? We know earth is rotating for which the incident angle of light varies, therefore magnetic flux through that plate should also vary and induce current. I'm confused whether it'll happen or not.

Comment: I don't know if the magnetic field part of sunlight can induce an emf, but I do know that the emf produced is proportional to the rate of change in the magnetic field.  The rate of change in the angle of sunlight is exceedingly small, so any induced emf from this rate of change will also be exceedingly small.

Comment: Maybe you meant a metal loop? Sunlight wouldn't pass through a metal plate. But it will certainly heat the metal plate. With a wire however, given the frequency of light and wavelength of light,  there would to many insurmountable problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let me break down my understanding of this topic.

As you say, Faraday's law tells us that a changing magnetic field will generate an electric field. You mention a metal plate. One example of Faraday's law in the case of a conductor is [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current). A nice example of eddy currents is when you drop a magnet though a metal tube, the magnet will generate eddy currents in the tube; the eddy currents will generate their own magnetic field, which slows down the magnet. This causes the magnet to take longer falling through a metal tube compared to a non-metal tube.

Now you mention sunlight. Sunlight is a form of electromagnetic radiation, and so it partly consists of a changing magnetic field. One can ask: does this changing magnetic field induce eddy currents in the plate?

As I understand it, the answer is yes, but we don't typically call them eddy currents. The EM wave (sunlight) will in general induce an EM wave in the metal plate. If you perform the math (see for example, Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics, section 9.4.2), you basically find that the light that strikes the plate is partly reflected, and partly transmitted. You *could* think of the reflected and transmitted waves as "induced" by the incident wave (the sunlight that strikes the plate), but I don't think that's how most physicists see the problem.